# How can I send accurate timestamp information from Android geolocation app to Postgresql database?

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, postgresql

First of all, sorry if my question seems too simple for you, I am only a beginner :-)
I have created a geolocation application split into two parts: an Android geolocation map that people use to add markers on their cell phone on an OpenStreetMaps basemap and an application accessible by browser that I can use to analyze these markers (I can do some simple statistics like display the number of markers A and B between time A and B for instance, between Sept. 1 and Sept. 4, or between 8 am and 8 pm on a certain day). This info is managed by my server using a Postgresql database.The server is in London but the people adding markers can be anywhere on the planet.

OK, so here is my question: when they add a marker on the map, how does the server knows the correct timestamp so that the time is registered accurately for each user, which in turn allows him to perform accurate statistics?

Since we won't have so many users, the developer I work with said that it was better to specify in Postgresql the timezone of the user, but he only allowed me to add + 2, - 2, etc, to the server time, which doesn't take into account daylight saving times etc. meaning I would need to change this time difference manually on the DST day. The developer told me that this was safer in case the time set on the user phone was not correct.

However, a developer friend told me that this was not the correct way to proceed, and that 
the time should be sent by the phone of each user, possibly using javascript with something like moment.js.

I am confused because I also read on the Postgresql documentation that it was possible to specify a timezone information there, including timezone with daylight savings time. I don't have the technical skills to do perform this task by myself so I would appreciate any guidance which I could provide to my developer, since this is really important for the application I am trying to build.

Any help regarding the standard procedure to follow in my case is appreciated, thank you very much everyone !

Best regards,

Philippe

```
<code>android<\code>
<code>mysql<\code>
<code>javascript<\code>
```

Comment: You have control over the clock on your own database server, but no control at all over the clocks on client devices.

Comment: So is it better to use timestamptz on the server to correct the time of the client according to his location, or should I take the time directly set in his phone?

Comment: Personally I would always use a server timestamp unless a time is being explicitly supplied by the user.  Store the time as UTC, and (if possible) store the geolocation information of the phone. It's always possible to display a UTC time in any alternative time zone of course.

Answer (score 1):

The devices (if phones) could vary a bit, and if picking their own time zones and submitting that, could vary wildly even if standing right next to each other and if they're rooted, no telling.

The best way to do this is on the database end. Create a field within your table that is something of type TIMESTAMP like "CreationTime" and then, when defining that table, ALSO set the default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

So this does all the work for you, you don't even have to write any code. Each time a new record is inserted, the server grabs the time and sticks it in there (on creation, not on later edits). All the times are relative to a known/controllable source and you're good to go.

Edit: Gah, just now saw "Postgresql" and the syntax above is for MySQL. Similar concept though.

Comment: Thank you, that is quite helpful already! Because I need to do statistics related to the local user time (for instance, only show markers added between March 1 and 30, 2013, and only from 8 am to 8pm) and not to the server time, I guess I should still offset the current timestamp by the time difference between user timezone and server timezone? What do you think?

Comment: I would grab as much as you can, and work on validity checks afterward. So, always grab the server time, because it's easy. Get the server timezone, just in case someone reboots it in a wacky way. Then see if you can get from the user's device what time zone they think it is, and what local time they think it is, and even what flags you might find for daylight savings time.